# fedora 20 screen command terminating automatically

Tags: fedora, gnu-screen

I have fedora 20; after last update, when I am using `screen` command, the terminal is closing instantly with message:

> [screen is terminating]

and not letting me to do anything with normal user, but
from root account everything is fine.
Any ideas what is wrong?

this is from root account, after typing "screen":
[image]

and this is when im typing "exit" after:

[image]

Comment: When asking for help, please provide the exact command you are using.

Comment: the command is "screen"

Comment: `screen command` terminates if `command` terminates. This is not a bug it simply is the behaviour of `screen`. Say `screen ls` gives you `[screen is terminating]`.

Comment: but from root account i when i'm typing "screen" it swithes to such a window and only if i'm typing "exit" after it, then the screen is terminating.

Comment: Please edit to add more information. What's the exact command you use? There seems to be a difference when being root or a non-privileged user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hit the same thing.  It seems to be caused by the following bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=884673

`# mount | grep devpts
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600)`

Remounting /dev/pts with proper permissions helped me:

`mount -o remount,gid=5,mode=620 /dev/pts`

And of course editing `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: nice, it helped